# Memory corruption in qt main thread after jailing a process

Tags: linux, webkit, qtwebkit, chroot

we are launching the qtApplication in a process.
Now process is jailed(using chroot).
Memory corruption occurred in the time of dlopen(platform.so) after jailing.

Example:

```
process main()
{
    mount "proc, sys, dev in /var/tt(chroot directory)"
    chroot("/var/tt");
    qtthread_create();
}


qtthread_create()
{
    create_thread_for_qt_app using pthread apis(qtMainThread);
    stack size is 256K;
}

qtMainThread()
{
    Printing stack size for qtMainThread(current thread) its displayed currently(256K).

    QApplication class creation(QApplication app).

    Printing stack size for qtMainThread(current thread) its displayed wrongly(junk value).   

    app.exec();
}
```

QApplication call trying load the platform.so using dlopen inside qt library. In that case stack size displayed wrongly.

Any body tried qt application under jailing circumstance.